# GUI in Java AWT

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

I started to learn Java and ended up with homework to make GUI ,but in Java AWT(not Swing). Sadly I came across two issues that i cannot find solution to.
1)After pressing the button on my first window the second window opens. How can i close it? All I can find(on stack or just google) in AWT is "System.exit(0)" which closes whole program.
2)I'd like to make a class that will mark whole TextField when I press it with left button of mouse (like when u press the website addres on your web browser).
I have no idea how to make it.

I wasn't able to find solutions to any of problems that I described above.

Comment: `Frame#setVisible`? Given the fact that just about every body no longers AWT (in over 16 years), find useful support is going to be troublesome

Comment: The first thing I would do is hit the [JavaDocs for `TextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/TextField.html) and skim through it's functionality, who knows, you might just [stumble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/TextComponent.html#selectAll--) across your answer

Answer (score 0):

1.you can use Frame.setVisible(false) method 
2.you have to use listeners
For further Reference use this link http://www.javatpoint.com/java-awt